# Crystal Report Page Size

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, page-size

I am new to Crystal Reports and wondering if there is some way of dealing with the `suppression` issues of `Sections`. I recently discovered that:

> When sum of heights of your sections (`Page Header`, `Details` and
>   `Page Footer`) is greater than the height of your `page`, last section
>   will `suppress` in the preview.

So problem is when my Data in `Details` section grows in size it suppresses preview.

How do we address such problems? How can I show my report on one single page? Should I estimate the `no. of records` that would be displayed in `Details` section and set `Page Size` accordingly? Will this be efficient?

Comment: Crystal Report dose not suppress anything unless you configure it to suppress. When sum of heights of your sections is greater than the height of your page crystal reports creates another page. in such cases page footer appears in both the pages

Comment: if it has moved to another page why don't I see it? Do we have to set some properties to enable this?

Comment: Click on Next Page ( > button) on Viewer. You should see it

Comment: I get this error "No valid report source is available.
" when I click on next page

Comment: You have to persist your report document across page Requests  Please read this http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/04/25/why-should-i-store-reports-object-in-httpsession

Comment: http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/11/03/persisting-crystal-reports-net-web-applications--ii